# How to delete specific blob file when that file has been removed from the source location via Azure Data Factory (self-hosted)

Tags: azure, etl, azure-data-factory

I created a Copy Data task in Azure Data Factory which will periodically copy modified files from my file system (self-hosted integration runtime) to an Azure Blob location. That works great when an existing file is modified or when a new file is created in the source, however, it won't delete a file from the blob destination when the corresponding file is deleted from the source file path location - since the file is gone, there is no modified date. Is there a way to keep the source and destination in sync via Azure Data Factory with individually deleted files such as in the scenario described above? Is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid to say Data Factory can't do that with actives, the pipeline only support read the exist file and copy them to sink. And sink side also doesn't support delete a file.

You can achieve that in code level, such as functions or notebook. After the copy finished, build a logic to compare the source and destination files list, delete the file which not exist in source list.

HTH.